# Commit issue with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am working on a module and the requirement is there is a producer and we are using kafka as queue for data producing and feeding it to consumer.

Now In consumer,I am trying to implement At-Least-Once messaging scenario.

For this i have to pool the messages from kafka and then consumer those.After consuming i am calling consumer.commitAsync(offset,Callback).

I want to know what will happen

Case 1). when commitAsync() api is never called(suppose there was an exception just before calling this api).In my case,I was supposing the message will be pumped again to consumer; but it is not happening.Consumer never get that data again.

Case 2). if the consumer reboots.

Below is the code snippet of properties set with the consumer

```
private Properties getConsumerProperties() {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "server");
        props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "groupName");
        props.put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, heartBeatinterval);
        props.put(METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, metaDataMaxAge);
        props.put(SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
        props.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
        props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        return props;
    }
```

Now in consumer, on the basis of some property set; i have 3 topics and create 3 consumers for each topic(as there are 3 partition and 3 brokers of kafka).

For consumption of data...I identify the packet in the basis of some propertywhen received fron kafka..and pass it to the relevant topic(i have taken a different thread pools for different topics and create the tasks on the basis of property in the packet and submit to thread pool).In the tasks, after processing i call the consumer.commitAsync(offset,callback).

I was expecting the same message to be pulled again from kafka in case of commitAsync is not called for some packet...but to my surprise it is not coming back...Am i missing something.Is there any sort of setting we need to do in the apache-kafka as well for At-Least-One.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is couple of things to be addressed in your question.

**Before I get to the suggestions on how to achieve at-least-once behavior, I'll try and address the 2 cases**:

> Case 1). when commitAsync() api is never called(suppose there was an
>   exception just before calling this api).In my case,I was supposing the
>   message will be pumped again to consumer; but it is not
>   happening.Consumer never get that data again.

The reason why your consumer does not get the old data could be because of the `enable.auto.commit` property, this is set to `true` by default and will commit the offsets regularly in the background. Due to this, the consumer on subsequent runs will find an offset to work with and will just wait for new data/messages to arrive.

> Case 2). if the consumer reboots.

This would also be similar i.e. if the consumer after rebooting finds a committed offset to work with, it will start consuming from that offset whether the offset was committed automatically due to the `enable.auto.commit` property set to `true` or by invoking `commitAsync()/commitSync()` explicitly.

**Now, moving to the part on how to achieve at-least-once behavior - I could think of the following 2 ways**:

1. If you want to take control of committing offsets, then set the "enable.auto.commit" property to `false` and then invoke `commitSync()` or `commitAsync()` with retries handled in the Callback function.

**Note**: The choice of Synchronous vs Asynchronous commit will depend on your latency budget and any other requirements. So, not going too much into those details here.

2. The other option is to utilise the automatic offset commit feature i.e. setting `enable.auto.commit` to `true` and `auto.commit.interval.ms` to an acceptable number (again, based on your requirements on how often would you like to commit offsets).

I think the default behaviour of Kafka is centered around at-least-once semantics, so it should be fairly straightforward.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Lalit..Thanks for your response...I am already doing it what you have said above.I have updated the question..Please have a look.

Comment: @Learner - I think the value `false` for enable.auto.commit needs to be a String i.e. in double quotes and not boolean. Could you please add double quotes and then try?

Comment: @Learner- If this doesn't work either, could you please share all of your code?

Comment: @Lalit..I think this is quite mis leading...if you check the documentation of the kafka which at "https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/" and search "enable.auto.commit" then it written its value will be in boolean...and that being said when i tried it with string..to my surprise it worked in one case; when user reboots the consumer after fixing the exception. it starts getting the messages again and i guess this is the expected behaviour...what do you say...but if this is the case then documentation is very misleading.

Comment: @Learner - After reading your message, I went back and tried it in my standalone cluster with the Boolean false and String and guess what - they both worked! Originally I thought we're passing the properties in the form of a map and probably during the initialisation, the [ConsumerCoordinator.java] (https://github.com/Paulf-999/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerCoordinator.java) is expecting a String but it actually expects a Boolean. Its odd that it doesn't accept Boolean in your case. any chance you could share your code for Consumer?

Comment: @Learner - Also, as we've moved on from the original question to solving a different mystery now i.e. Boolean false vs String ("false"). Could you please acknowledge my answer to your question? i.e. if you're happy with the approach to achieving the at-least-once-semantics? :)

We can continue with Boolean vs String part either here in the comments or put that up as a new post for the entire community to benefit, if that's okay with you? :)